# NoSuchField error in java code but field exists

Tags: java, nosuchfieldexception

I have the following code.

```
public  class Table {

    Integer[] data;

    public Table() {
        this.data = new Integer[100];
    }

    public boolean insert(int key){
        data[53] = 1;
         return true;
    }
 }

&& 

public class test{

private Table tab;

protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        tab = new Table();
    }

public void testInsertTable() {
        tab.insert(1);
        assertTrue(tab.data[53] == 1);  // error here
    }
}
```

The test class is run using JUnit.
The code works when i run in it Eclipse but i get a NoSuchField error on the line pointed by the comment when i run it outside of Eclipse.

The class responsible for the problem is Table, that much i know for certain.

Comment: As per java doc, the error is thrown, if an application tries to access or modify a specified field of an object, and that object no longer has that field. Check in junit, if you are getting Table correctly. Moreover `Integer[] data;` is a package protected field and not public. So if your test class is in same package, then only it will work

Answer (score 1):

What could be wrong is you are not using `@Before` annotation on the setup method

The correct code should be

```
public class test{

private Table tab;

@Before
 protected void setUp() throws Exception {
       tab = new Table();
  }

@Test
public void testInsertTable() {
        tab.insert(1);
        assertTrue(tab.data[53] == 1);  // error here
 }
 }
```

Comment: The test class is not made by me,Its a pre-defined class i have limited access to,so i cannot modify it.